# How to print 2D array like matrix using python.?

Tags: python

I am trying to learn python by myself. I am trying to print 2-D array but cannot get any luck.

here is the code

```
rows = 10
colms = 10
grid=[]

for row in range(0,9):
    for colm in range(0,9):
       print(grid[row][colm])
```

the error i get is " list out of index". I have tired different things like

```
grid[[rows],[colms]]
```

but could not get far.

How can i print out a 2-D array like a matrix

Comment: what does `print( len(grid), len(grid[0]) )` tell you?

Comment: grid currently has nothing in it, and it 1 dimensional

Comment: You might want to consider using numpy or pandas here to make your life easier. You can just write `grid=np.zeros((rows, colms))` for a simple 2D array, or `grid=np.asmatrix(np.zeros((rows,colms))` for a matrix that knows how to do things like cross products.

Answer (score 1):

`grid` has no entries in it yet, so any attempt to access a member at any index in it will fail. You must fill it with values first.

For example:

```
In [11]: grid = []

In [12]: for i in range(10):
   ....:     row = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
   ....:     grid.append(row)
   ....:

In [13]: grid
Out[13]:
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

In [14]: grid[9][9]
Out[14]: 0
```

(Note that you must create each row in grid as a separate object, if they are all the same row object editing will cause them all to be edited!)

EDIT: To input into the grid, do something like this:

```
In [15]: grid[0][0] = int(raw_input("input: "))
input: 1

In [16]: grid
Out[16]:
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: How can i make it a so that user can input into an array? Do i just use input?